# How to centre the same asset/drawables between Splash Screen Activity and other activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I'have created the splash screen without any layout xml file but this is done by the vector drawable with centring the app logo like below:

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
```

But I also would like to show the same app logo in the next subsequent screen. For e.q. In my case let us say Main Activity screen where I've a layout xml where I've centred the icon with the constraint layout.

activity_main.xml

```
    <!-- By adding android:layout_marginTop="26dp" to the ImageView kind of works but not sure why the magic number works
     Not sure where to get the same number for some other devices-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/splash_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/splash_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_invest_logo" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I noticed when the same asset logo swap happens between Splash and Main Activity I can see a jumpy behaviour with the logos.

Appreciate your help. Below is the github for the entire source code.

https://github.com/nksaroj/InvestApp

You can see the jumpy issue with the green logo here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Layout has happened here.

                float statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight() * 1f;

                //This is tricks where Samsung and some other devices don't consider the height in splash screen so that you need to adjust the height manually 
                View navigationBarBackground = findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);

                if (navigationBarBackground == null) {
                    statusBarHeight = statusBarHeight * -1f;
                }

                imageViewIconY = imageViewReadyIcon.getY() + (statusBarHeight / 2);

                imageViewIconY.setY(imageViewIconY);



                // Don't forget to remove your listener when you are done with it.
                getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```